# Transition effect on parent element when destroying child elements within it

Tags: css

I'm trying to figure out how to **transition** the height of a *parent* div when a *child* element within it is destroyed.  I'm using fadeOut() to remove the child element, and have tried applying `transition: height 2s;` to the parent div, but the smooth transition does not seem to occur when I destroy the child element.  I have also tried `transition: all 2s`, but that does not seem to work either.  I couldn't find any other question whose answers satisfied what I am looking for.  The parent div is of the 'option' class.. here is the css on the parent div:

```
.option {
    color: #052101;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px black;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transition: all 2s;
}
```

Comment: You're saying that you're using "fadeOut()" which makes me assume that you're using jQuery. Why not use jQuery `animate` method animate the height change then?

Comment: You can't transition between unknown values. You have no height set on the div so the CSS doesn't "know" what the height is. It's the old "transition to auto height" problem. I would suggest that instead of 'fadeOut" you use "slideUp"

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks!  That is a great work around solution.